# Maintaining "date" format when importing from Google sheet Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a dataset that I imported from Google sheets where all values in the "date" column were formatted as `DD-MM-YYYY`. However, once the data are imported into Excel, some values maintain the original format while others change to `MM/DD/YYYY`.
The format of the last two rows below in Excel is Date, and I have tried changing the format to be General like the first two rows and maintain the original format with no luck. I have done this through the "Number" then "Custom" and "Date" tabs.

[image]

```
29-02-2012
29-02-2012
1/3/2012
3/3/2012
```

My goal is to simply unify the "date" format so that I can later correctly import the data into R.

I converted all date values into text, per my understanding of the solution below, and the values look as below:

```
29-02-2012
40911
```

where the values that were MM/DD/YYYY are now "40911"

Comment: Excel will do exactly that if 1) the dates in Sheets are text strings and not real dates (try `ISTEXT(cell_ref)` to check that); 2) the windows regional settings on your computer for date is `MDY`; and 3) you have not taken any measures to tell Excel the format of the incoming dates.  You will note that the dates that are retained as text will all have the number in the first segment >12.  You will need to change your import method to tell Excel the proper settings (or change your Windows Regional Format to DMY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your result. If I import the string 29-02-2012 in Excel then it is reformatted to the current date format, too. Only invalid dates like 29-02-2021 are left untouched.

That said, Excel is well known for arbitrarily converting imported data when it thinks it recognizes the type. Specifically, every string looking like a valid date in any of the notations known to Excel is converted to an internal timestamp representation, destroying the meaning in case the string wasn't intended as a date. (Similarly, everything looking like a number is converted to internal number representation, including IP addresses in which the second, third and fourth octet happen bigger than or equal to 100.) The only way to avoid that is to format your cells as text.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Do you recommend formatting cells as text in the original Google sheet file, or once it's imported to Excel?

Comment: I have no experience with Google Sheets but generally, when importing to Excel you get to choose the type of each column. That would be the point where you select Text instead of Date or General.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a year since you posted this but I will post the answer so someone else can benefit from it.

So, I had the same issue, excel was misinterrpreting dates from 1st to 12th because that is how many months there are, the rest of the dates would be imported just fine.

I don't know the reason but it could be because of the USA format in google sheets because I imported like 30 sheets and all of them were in USA format in google sheets and I had the same issue with each sheet.

So what we can do is, go to "Text to Columns" section and change the Date format to MDY. After that, once again we change the format like how you did, Custom -> dd/mm/yyyy. That is all you need to do, I tried this and it worked for me! and I am sure it will work for you as well. :)

Comment: Thanks, it has been nearly two years actually hahaha! but still useful answer.